# Install4j is not keeping link in prebuild JREs for MacOS

Tags: install4j

in our install4j script we are using a prebuild jre. The tar.gz file contains a link for MacOS and Linux. When installing on linux, the link is kept. When installing on MacOS (in Version 8.0.8, it did work in 8.0.4), the link is replaced by a real file.

```
Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib -> ../Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib
```

After installing, the file Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib is not a link any more, but a real file. It seems that the Eclipse-launcher has a problem with this, it does not start with this error:

```
Error: could not find libjava.dylib
Failed to GetJREPath()
```

If the file `Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib` is changed back to a link, the Eclipse-Launcher will start again.

I have a temporary solution in my setup.install4j script to remove that file and create a link (action for both exists), but it would be nice to to modify the links in the tar.gz of a prebuild jre.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to fully sign and notarize a JDK bundle on macOS, the file `Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib` cannot be a symlink.

See

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8235687

These are new requirements from Apple that have been introduced by notarization.

However, recent JDK versions fix the problems introduced by that change:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8238225